# SQL De-Para juntando dados diferentes

Tags: sql, select, join

tenho uma consulta me tirando a paciência, tenho que juntar duas tabelas de anos diferentes, porém os codigos de referencia mudaram de um ano para outro. Como faço para manter as informações na mesma linha.

Tabela 1

```
Ano  | Codigo Produto | Nome produto | Valor
-----+----------------+--------------+------
2019 | XX             | Caneta       | 100
2019 | YY             | Lapis        | 150
2019 | ZZ             | Papel        | 50
```

Tabela 2

```
Ano  | Codigo Produto | Nome produto | Valor
-----+----------------+--------------+------
2018 | SS             | Caneta A     | 100
2018 | GG             | Lapis X      | 150
2018 | ZZ             | Papel        | 80
```

Tabela de Resultado

```
Ano  | Codigo Produto | Nome produto | Valor | Ano  | Codigo Produto | Nome produto | Valor
-----+----------------+--------------+-------+------+----------------+--------------+------
2019 | XX             | Caneta       | 100   | 2018 | SS             | Caneta A     | 100
2019 | YY             | Lapis        | 150   | 2018 | GG             | Lapis X      | 150
2019 | ZZ             | Papel        | 50    | 2018 | ZZ             | Papel        | 80
```

Como vocês podem ver eu preciso juntar ambos os dados numa mesma linha, porém não tem nada igual nas linhas 1 e 2 das tabelas, eu precisaria dizer que o código Produto 2018 "SS" é igual ao código Produto 2019 "XX" e que "YY" é igual a "GG".

Alguém poderia ajudar nesta encrenca?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse caso não tem muita mágica a se fazer não. A solução ideal seria criar uma Tabela de De Para e utilizá-la como intermediária no JOIN.

Tabela DE_PARA

```
Codigo Produto T1    | Codigo Produto T2
---------------------+--------------------
XX                   | SS
YY                   | GG
ZZ                   | ZZ
```

Então o Join ficaria algo como

```
SELECT 
    T1.ANO,
    T1.CODIGO_PRODUTO,
    T1.NOME_PRODUTO,
    T1.VALOR,
    T2.ANO,
    T2.CODIGO_PRODUTO,
    T2.NOME_PRODUTO,
    T2.VALOR,
FROM TABELA_1 T1
INNER JOIN DE_PARA
      ON T1.CODIGO_PRODUTO = DE_PARA.CODIGO_PRODUTO_T1
INNER JOIN TABELA_2 T2
      ON T2.CODIGO_PRODUTO = DE_PARA.CODIGO_PRODUTO_T2
```

Comment: Ok Arthur, obrigado pela ajuda, vou tentar.